# TranslateXBy move at constant speed

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a small app that slides multiple images across the screen. I want to slide the images at a constant speed so they remain the same distance apart.

I am trying to use animate and setduration but it the animation slows down at the end

```java
myImageView.animate().translationXBy(-2500f).setDuration(500);
```

Comment: What is your problem??

Comment: The translation doesn't move at a constant speed - so it start quickly and slows down near the end. Is there some way to make the views move at a constant speed? @Robbit

Comment: You can use RecycleView to do this.